# Length of the array returned by document.querySelectorAll is always 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, queryselector

```js
function checkFilled() {
  let inputElements = document.querySelectorAll("table .table_element input");
  let outputElement = document.querySelector("#output");
  outputElement.innerHTML = "You entered : ";
  console.log(inputElements.length);

  for (let [index, inputElement] of inputElements.entries()) {
    outputElement.innerHTML += " " + index + " " + inputElement.value;
    if (inputElement.value == "") {
      inputElement.style = "background-color: red;";
    } else {
      inputElement.style = "background-color: green;";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="first">
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">First Name :</p>
    <input name="import_date_visit" id="subEmail" type="text" required size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="Claudio">
  </div>
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Last name :</p>
    <input name="import_date_visit" type="text" required size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="MISSING VALUE">
  </div>
</table>
<p id="output">You entered : nothing yet</p>
```

Whenever I input anything in to one of the input fields, `0` gets logged to the console, and the inputs don't change the color. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, but I can't find it for half an hour already …

Comment: That's invalid markup. `<div>` is invalid child of `<table>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because your **`table` is not valid** and browser parses your code as (try this in devtools):

```html
<div class="table_element">
   <p style="text-align: center;">First Name :</p>
   <input name="import_date_visit" id="subEmail" type="text" required="" size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="Claudio">
</div>
<div class="table_element">
   <p style="text-align: center;">Last name :</p>
   <input name="import_date_visit" type="text" required="" size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="MISSING VALUE">
</div>
<table class="first"></table>
```

as you can see **`table` is not wrapping your elements anymore** because `div` is not valid child for it. It works if you try selector without `table`:

```js
function checkFilled() {
  let inputElements = document.querySelectorAll(".table_element input");
  let outputElement = document.querySelector("#output");
  outputElement.innerHTML = "You entered : ";
  console.log(inputElements.length);

  for (let [index, inputElement] of inputElements.entries()) {
    outputElement.innerHTML += " " + index + " " + inputElement.value;
    if (inputElement.value == "") {
      inputElement.style = "background-color: red;";
    } else {
      inputElement.style = "background-color: green;";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="first">
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">First Name :</p>
    <input name="import_date_visit" id="subEmail" type="text" required size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="Claudio">
  </div>
  <div class="table_element">
    <p style="text-align: center;">Last name :</p>
    <input name="import_date_visit" type="text" required size="25" oninput="checkFilled();" value="MISSING VALUE">
  </div>
</table>
<p id="output">You entered : nothing yet</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to select the inputs as children of a table `document.querySelectorAll("table .table_element input");` but there is none. Remove "table" from the selector and it works as expected `document.querySelectorAll(".table_element input");`